# Mesh partially wrinkling when armature moves

Tags: mesh, armature, inverse-kinematics

I'm new to Blender and am having an issue with some joints wrinkling when moving the armature. In the attached image the left knee is exhibiting this problem, while the right knee is bending as I want it to. Weight painting doesn't seem to be helping (either heavily painted or lightly painted I still get the wrinkle).

All my other joints work just fine. Any ideas? I'm using Blender 2.80.

Picture of problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqaqX.jpg

Blender file: https://tinyurl.com/wp6n6z8

Comment: The mesh topology is bad in the left knee. Somehow you swapped the middle edgeloop and the lower one. Swap them back first, then try to repaint the weight.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)